# Flutter - How can i make full height with scroll as a SliverAppBar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, layout, flutter-layout

On my layout I made like 2 main widgets. Both of them is expanded widgets. First One is holding welcome message and a input. Second one will be my main content. When i scroll second one i want to first one will disappear and my second widget (main content) will be full screen as SliverAppBar. I tried use SliverAppBar. But SliverAppBar's flexibleSpaces just accepting Image and title. How can i make it ? Thanks for answers!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SliverPersistentHeader` with `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` in `slivers` attribute of `SliverAppbar` as mentioned in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450225/15119028)